# openssl version keeps the old one

Tags: centos7, openssl

I'm trying to update openssl on CentOS 7.3. I tried at the beginning to update it using `yum update openssl-devel`' but it says : `No packages marked for update`

When I'm running `yum info openssl` the version number that appears is : `1.0.1e`

Afterwards I installed openssl 1.0.2i from source using this [guide](http://www.ehowstuff.com/how-to-install-and-update-openssl-on-centos-6-centos-7/) on CentOS 7.3. I think that my problem is in these two lines:

```
mv /usr/bin/openssl /root/
ln -s /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl /usr/bin/openssl
```

In both cases when I'm running openssl version after the installation, I'm stil see the old one:

```
openssl version
OpenSSL 0.9.8l 5 Nov 2009
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Which distro are you using ?

Comment: Add a lot more details about your environment, including the steps you followed. No one wants to read an external guide to try to come up with an idea what you might have done wrong.

Comment: I edited the question yesterday. I added some technical details about my environment and the things i done, please reopen the question.

Comment: Following any part of that guide is a mistake. At this point you should probably restore the system from backups taken from before you embarked on this adventure, or reinstall the system from scratch. It may not be possible to fix it otherwise.

Comment: `What could be the problem?` cluelessness

Comment: @MichaelHampton Why following the guide is mistake?

Comment: The whole premise is wrong. You do not need to "update" openssl by downloading the source and building it yourself in order to resolve security issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really don't think you're giving us the full picture here. You almost certainly didn't 'just follow' the linked document. If you did then you would not have `OpenSSL 0.9.8l 5 Nov 2009` from 7 years ago on your system. At this point you should consider your system horribly misconfigured and you should just reinstall it.

If you want to update your openssl because you have security concerns based upon the apparent version number then you need to read up on and understand about backporting. RHEL (upstream for CentOS) backport security fixes into their products. You can use the command

```
rpm -q --changelog openssl
```

to look at the changelog. You should then check to see that the vulnerabilities you are concerned about are listed, they almost certainly will be.

For reference the C7.3 system I have to hand

```
openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
```

and

rpm -q --changelog openssl

```
 Thu Sep 22 2016 Tomáš Mráz <tmraz@redhat.com> 1.0.1e-60
- fix CVE-2016-2177 - possible integer overflow
- fix CVE-2016-2178 - non-constant time DSA operations
- fix CVE-2016-2179 - further DoS issues in DTLS
- fix CVE-2016-2180 - OOB read in TS_OBJ_print_bio()
- fix CVE-2016-2181 - DTLS1 replay protection and unprocessed records issue
- fix CVE-2016-2182 - possible buffer overflow in BN_bn2dec()
- fix CVE-2016-6302 - insufficient TLS session ticket HMAC length check
- fix CVE-2016-6304 - unbound memory growth with OCSP status request
- fix CVE-2016-6306 - certificate message OOB reads
- mitigate CVE-2016-2183 - degrade all 64bit block ciphers and RC4 to 
  112 bit effective strength
...
```

So as recently as September security fixes were backported into OpenSSL.